# add custom directive in element programmatically instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I like to add custom directory in element which is run-time added from script.

eg: **`<input type="number" my-focus = "focusField" >`** in this i am adding 'my-focus' directive from html.

Can I add this directive from JavaScript because my element is dynamically added and I want to add focus on that element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

Here is an example

```
$scope.html = $compile('<a ng-click="click()" href="#">Click me</a>')($scope);
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope','$compile',
      function($scope, $compile) {
        $scope.html = $compile('<a ng-click="click()" href="#">Click me</a>')($scope);

        angular.element(document.querySelector('#x')).append($scope.html);

        $scope.click = function() {
          console.log('Yahoooooooooooo')
        }
      }
    ]);

})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div id="x">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Satpal for your help